# Define a function for df using a pandas serie

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function

I would like to calculate the number of people (dataframe variable) for a sector (ROME column) belonging to a workgroup (FAP column) for each year that I divide by the total number of people in that workgroup.

[image: Dataframe]

The total number of workgroups is stored in a variable Total_FAP :

```
    Total_FAP = df2.Total
    Total_FAP.head()
```

which shows

```
FAP
Agents administratifs et commerciaux des transports et du tourisme                                 63160.0
Agents d'entretien                                                                                718150.0
Agents d'exploitation des transports                                                              142680.0
Agents de gardiennage et de sécurité                                                              465010.0
Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons                                                  121040.0
```

For example, for the year 2010, I have to take the number of people for the ROME A1101 corresponding to the FAP "Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons " (which is 2630) and divide it by the total number that is in the pandas series (which is 121040).
It would make something like : 2630/121040 = 0.02172835426

I would like to know if there is a way to make a function, because I wanted to try to make an iteration on the dataframes but I saw that it was not advised....

Thanks for your help

EDIT: Here is the raw data for DF1

```
{'FAP': {0: 'Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons',
  1: 'Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons',
  2: 'Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons',
  3: 'Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons',
  4: 'Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons'},
 'ROME': {0: 'A1101', 1: 'A1201', 2: 'A1202', 3: 'A1203', 4: 'A1204'},
 '2010': {0: 2630, 1: 1380, 2: 4450, 3: 20330, 4: 130},
 '2011': {0: 2790, 1: 1500, 2: 3670, 3: 20040, 4: 90},
 '2012': {0: 2700, 1: 1320, 2: 4020, 3: 19130, 4: 130},
 '2013': {0: 2970, 1: 1690, 2: 3520, 3: 20500, 4: 140},
 '2014': {0: 2680, 1: 1980, 2: 2790, 3: 16900, 4: 150},
 '2015': {0: 2440, 1: 1780, 2: 2640, 3: 16310, 4: 170},
 '2016': {0: 3600, 1: 1980, 2: 2540, 3: 17680, 4: 90},
 '2017': {0: 2930, 1: 2470, 2: 2510, 3: 18520, 4: 130},
 '2018': {0: 2740, 1: 2010, 2: 2130, 3: 19280, 4: 150},
 '2019': {0: 1600.0, 1: 1760.0, 2: 1050.0, 3: 14260.0, 4: 80.0},
 '2020': {0: 11140, 1: 6490, 2: 14000, 3: 76570, 4: 510},
 '1e Trimestre 2021': {0: 600, 1: 560, 2: 300, 3: 6090, 4: 30}}
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"stored in a pandas series"*? Do you mean in a column? what is the type of `df.iloc[0, 0]` please? And can you replace your image by data in raw format?

Comment: Thanks @Corralien I've edited my post :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use:

```
cols = df.filter(regex='^\d{4}$').columns
df = df.merge(Total_FAP, left_on='FAP', right_index=True, suffixes=('', '_total'))
df[cols].div(df['FAP_total'], axis=0)
```

output:

```
       2010      2011      2012      2013      2014      2015      2016      2017      2018      2019      2020
0  0.021728  0.023050  0.022307  0.024537  0.022141  0.020159  0.029742  0.024207  0.022637  0.013219  0.092036
1  0.011401  0.012393  0.010905  0.013962  0.016358  0.014706  0.016358  0.020406  0.016606  0.014541  0.053619
2  0.036765  0.030321  0.033212  0.029081  0.023050  0.021811  0.020985  0.020737  0.017597  0.008675  0.115664
3  0.167961  0.165565  0.158047  0.169365  0.139623  0.134749  0.146067  0.153007  0.159286  0.117812  0.632601
4  0.001074  0.000744  0.001074  0.001157  0.001239  0.001404  0.000744  0.001074  0.001239  0.000661  0.004213
```

Comment: Thank you @mozway for your answer, but it's not really a mean... it's someting more like for example, for the year 2010, I have to take the number of people for the ROME A1101 corresponding to the FAP "Agriculteurs, éleveurs, sylviculteurs, bûcherons " (which is 2630) and divide it by the total number that is in the pandas series (which is 121040). It would make something like : 2630/121040 = 0.02172835426 (it's on the post already)

Comment: @BillyPocheo the problem is that you provided an incomplete dataset, I do not know what `121040` is ;) Can you try `df[cols]/df[cols].sum()`?

Comment: It's on the variable Total_FAP ;) @mozway

Comment: @BillyPocheo then the provided data is incomplete, there is no `Total_FAP`, please provide it. I don't know it's format/content

Comment: I swear there is Total_FAP since the beginning xD

Comment: You mean `Total_FAP = df2.Total`? both `df2` and `Total` are undefined…

Comment: @BillyPocheo OK I updated the answer, next time please provide all the data as dataframes, here the numbers were hidden. This would have saved everyone's time ;)

Comment: @BillyPocheo so is it now what you want? ;)

Comment: Yes it worked :) Thank you @mozway and everyone !